# Changing map styling in mapbox using mapbox.js?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, cartocss

I am using **mapbox.js** for this.

i am working on the project which requires to change the styling of map, eg: area,land and water colors on click of certain button. one possible way is,
 **i use different project_ids and toggle between layer** which can be easily achieved. but i want to use same project_id and hence i have to then change the style of map using javascript code dynamically. at one place i found that i can use cartoCSS for this. but i dont know anything about using it in mapbox.

Comment: What is the source of your map tiles/WMS? Does it support changing of symbology?

Comment: i am using mapbox. and mapbox uses Openstreetmap.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are loading maptiles from your mapbox account--using something like [L.mapbox.tileLayer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.4/l-mapbox-tilelayer/) there is no way to change the style of tiles client side.  Your options would be:

- load the data you want to be able to style dynamically as vector data, displayed on top of your raster tilelayer, using something like [L.mapbox.featureLayer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.4/l-mapbox-featurelayer/) and [L.mapbox.simplestyle](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.4/l-mapbox-simplestyle-style/).  Then, change its style via javascript.  Of course, loading large vector sources (particularly complex polygons) into your browser can cause the browser to slow down or freeze.  Loading as a [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki) rather than geojson can help.
- check out mapbox-gl, *still in beta*, particularly [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-styles/).  To style your data w/ mapbox-gl, upload the source vector tiles to your mapbox account with **MapBox Studio**, and style it in browser using its [json-based style spec](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/).

*caveat: you **can** style raster tiles via css, just as you would style any `<img />`.  E.g. you can apply css image filters.  It doesn't sound like this is what you're looking for though.*